# Advice for set-up of VirtualBox(?) server for testing purposes

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, remote-access, server

I'd like to ask for advice for the following use-case:

We are looking into setting up a server that has several virtual machines on there, so that we can test our websites on a wide range of OS's/browsers. Therefor we would like to have the following features:

- A server that can run several virtual machines simultaniously
- The possibility to remotely access these machines - obviously with authentication
- The possibility to be able to run two instances of the same virtual machine simultaniously (e.g. tester #1 and tester #2 should be able to test at the same time)

Are there any open source projects that facilitate this? I am currently looking into setting up an Ubuntu box with VirtualBox on there - but I have a hard time on figuring out finding relevant sources (i'm probably Googling the wrong terms).

Thanks, and happy holidays,

Gerben van Dijk

P.S. Is this the right place to ask for advice?

Comment: Have you looked at Vagrant + VirtualBox? Sounds like you will need to bind the different virtual machines to different ports on the host.

Comment: @neurite yes, I am actively looking into Vagrant as well (we use that already a lot in our development workflow). In your opinion, would the above scenario be viable and if so, how would you do it?

Comment: Actually I don't think I fully understand the requirements. But in general Vagrant allows to script the virtual machines which is a step up from using VirtualBox directly. Another possibility is Docker. I don't have experience with it myself. People claim Vagrant is more for development while Docker is for deployment. You can also use both.

Comment: Here are two links that might be helpful for your use case: 1) [How to set up Vagrant + Docker](http://mark.stratmann.me/articles/implementing-a-vagrant-docker-development-environment) and 2) [open source configuration management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software). The 2nd link points to a Wiki page where you will see more options.